# Change frame values of an IBOutletCollection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have created IBOutletCollect of couple buttons :

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *allButtons;
```

Now I have to change the frame and position of these buttons :

```
[_allButtons makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setFrame:) withObject: ????? ];
```

how can set my custom values as id here ? I used this method but compiler gives me an error

```
    [_allButtons makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setFrame:) withObject:CGRectMake(10, 0, 0, 10)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CGRect is not an object so it can't be added directly.
Wrap it in a NSValue:

```
[NSValue valueWithCGRect:]
```

have a look
[NSValue Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 3):

Enumerate your array using a block:

```
[allButtons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *button, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    button.frame = newFrame;
};];
```

Much more powerful and flexible, and probably faster as well.

Answer (score 0):

A CGRect is not an object, so you'll have to wrap it in an NSValue object and then create a category method that does the unwrapping and setting of the frame:

```
[_allButtons makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(updateFrame:) withObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(10, 0, 0, 10)]];
```

In a category on UIView:

```
- (void)updateFrame:(NSValue *)frameValue {
    self.frame = [frameValue CGRectValue];
}
```

Comment: @jrturton: Yeah, I would have done it with a loop, but I wanted to stick to the author's original solution as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you.

```
for (UIButton *btn in allButtons) {
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(setFrame:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
};
```